# Find a matching interference suppression capacitor

Tags: capacitor

I have a broken interference suppression capacitor that needs to be replaced for a tool of mine, but there is none of that exact type available any more. Without knowing what specs to look for it's very difficult to know if I can replace the capacitor with another one or not.

These are the specs of the current capacitor:

- 5 cables
- 0.2 µF + 2x 2500 pF XY
- 250 V ~ 8 A HPG

[image: current capacitor]

I have found the following that look at least somehow similar:

but there are still differences, e.g.

[link 1](https://www.amazon.de/Flex-El-Kondensator-X1Y-22/dp/B002J61FZW/ref=asc_df_B002J61FZW/?tag=googshopde-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=463195091982&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=9237857796474769702&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=20044&hvtargid=pla-951875130362&psc=1&th=1&psc=1)

- 8 A vs 6 A
- 2x 2500 pF XY vs 2x 2400 pF X1+Y2

[link 2](https://www.limmert.com/alle-artikel/lichttechnik/betriebsgeraete/kondensator/104311-europ-funkentstoerkondensa-0-2mf-und-2x2400pf-bv18300/48/250v-36ko091-sku01360618)

- 8 A vs 10 A
- 2x 2500 pF XY vs 2x 2400 pF X1Y2

Are those differences relevant for operation? What are the values to watch out for? And if one of the two is worth trying, which one?

---

**UPDATE:** link 2 worked for my specific device

Comment: More than just a capacitor, it is a power line LC filter module.  "5 cables" = 2 AC input lines, 2 AC output lines, 1 Earth Ground.

Comment: @Nedd thanks for the info & sorry for my ignorance: Is every "capacitor" with "5 cables = 2 AC input lines, 2 AC output lines, 1 Earth Ground." a "power line LC filter module"? Or if not, how did you get to that conclusion?

Comment: The 5 wire/pin configuration is very common for an AC line filter. There are standard capacitors with multiple wires/pins, but they are usually are marked differently, once very common in old style tube radios/televisions. As in the other answer the higher current part is a better replacement option. Also be sure to connect the new part in the same orientation as the original, the ground wire often faces the AC line input.  Here is some additional info on AC line filter modules: https://www.edn.com/match-modular-emi-ac-line-filters-to-applications-dc-supply-needs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values can be within a fairly wide tolerance; 2400pF is no problem.  The current rating however must meet or exceed, which rules out #1.

There should be an inductor in there also (hence the current rating), but no value is given.  Presumably it will be a lower value, at the higher current rating, if the package sizes are similar.  Maybe it's still within tolerance.

Comment: I don't quite understand if the part about the inductor. Is that a problem, or is this likely some internal about one (or both) units (the original one; and/or link #2)?
Package sizes (size of the actual unit in cm/inch) is almost identical.
"Maybe it's still within tolerance" --> I understand from that it's worth a try to buy #2